# Is there any SimpleLOngProperty in javafx if not then what to do?

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview

I am working with `javafx2.2`. I am creating a table using `tableview`, my data is of different type. int,string,float,double have `SimpleIntegerProperty`, `SimpleFloatProperty`,  `SimpleDoubleProperty`, `SimpleStringproperty`

But what to do for long , char , TimeStamp and float sequence.

I need to use these because of sorting performance see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805845/javafx-tableview-sort-is-really-slow-how-to-improve-sort-speed-as-in-java-swing)

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create ObjectProperty like that

```
ObjectProperty<Float> floatObjectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Float>();
ObjectProperty<Long> longObjectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Long>();
ObjectProperty<Timestamp> timestampObjectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Timestamp>();
```

And use it like any ohter property