# Improve deleting row performance in javafx table

Tags: java, performance, javafx-2, tableview, tablecolumn

I am trying to delete row from javafx table by using this code

```
new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                int index = RNG.nextInt(table.getItems().size());
                table.getItems().remove(index); 
              }
        }.start();
```

but deletion performance is very bad.

Any suggestion on how to improve it.

**EDIT:** I have **48** columns

Comment: Can you explain bad performance? Time consuming, freezing, sluggish GUI experience? If you want improve performance, you need to provide more codes? Or try your with a simpler demo code.

Comment: Bad performance in terms of gui freezing and more time consumption, slow scrolling and selection....

you can consider my use case as creating a table with 48 columns of type "order" (mainly object property of different type.). I have provided cellvaluefactory for fast sorting check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805845/javafx-tableview-sort-is-really-slow-how-to-improve-sort-speed-as-in-java-swing)

Comment: the same problem happen with me....i am also add more jar for hibernate.

Comment: try to delete by breaking list in two parts one before index and one after index and then combine these two parts