# JavaFx Tableview speed and sorting in Sql application

Tags: java, sql, performance, tableview

I am working on a small, toy application to expand my knowledge about `Java` `JavaFx` and `Sql`. I have a MySQL server in my local network, which I am able to communicate with and a simple Tableview can be populated, sorted ... etc. The data has only to be shown to the user, no editing. Everything nice and clean.

**The Problems:**

- There are around 170 000 rows with 10 col., all `chars`, to display, which seems to be rather hard to do in reasonable time. The query is done during startup and it take around 1 1/2 min before I can see the table.
- Also the memory footprint is enormous, the application without populated Tableview around 70 mb, with all the data it has 600-700 mb (the xml file which is used to populate the mysql is 70 mb in size ... ) !
- Sorting is REALLY slow, I am using Stringproperty which should give a boost according to: [JavaFx tableview sort is really slow how to improve sort speed as in java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805845/javafx-tableview-sort-is-really-slow-how-to-improve-sort-speed-as-in-java-swing) (If I understood that correctly) However the custom sort, I did not try so far.

**My thoughts:**

Similar to the application design for mobile, I think an adapter-pattern can fix these problems. Hence, I create an `OberservableList` with the correct size of elements, but only populate a limit of rows in the beginning. When I am scrolling done (scroll wheel) the List has to be updated with new elements in advance via `sql-queries`. This should give me a performance boost for the first Problem. Nice idea but what am I going to do if the user is going to scroll done via the scrollbar(click and drag down), then I would skip certain entries, but I need the information to give the user the feedback where to scroll to.
How could I fix this ?

For the sorting, I would use the sql sorting methods, so each sort will be performed on the sql server and a new OberservableList will be created. As before, only a certain amount of data would be loaded in the first query.

If this approach would also effect the memory footprint, I am not sure.

**Your opinion:**
Are my ideas reasonable and do-able in `Java`, `JavaFx` ?
I would love to hear your ideas about these problems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that [JVx](http://www.sibvisions.com/de/jvx) is capable of providing the lazy-loading function. This should do the trick